# Replace zookeeper server from zookeeper ensemble (with SolrCloud)

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have a SolrCloud cluster (6.6) setup with external Zookeeper Ensemble (3.4.8) of 5 nodes. Recently, one machine (ip1:port1) that run 1 Zookeeper with id=1 went down. This is what I've done to replace zookeeper:

- Start zookeeper in another machine with the same id (=1).
- Change zoo.cfg in 4 live zookeeper to match new zookeeper server and restart.
- Update ZK_HOST variable in solr.in.sh to match new zookeeper server.
- Restart solr.

After that, my solr cluster seemed to functioning well, but in solr.log, it looked like solr client and zookeeper servers still try to connect to the old zookeeper:

Solr log

```
2017-12-01 15:04:38.782 WARN  (Timer-0-SendThread(ip1:port1)) [   ] o.a.z.ClientCnxn Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 30029ms for sessionid 0x0

2017-12-01 15:04:40.807 WARN  (Timer-0-SendThread(ip1:port1)) [   ] o.a.z.ClientCnxn Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 31030ms for sessionid 0x0
```

Zookeeper log:

```
2017-12-01 13:53:57,972 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(ip1:port1):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1032] - Opening socket connection to server ip1:port1. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2017-12-01 13:54:03,972 [myid:] - WARN  [main-SendThread(ip1:port1):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1162] - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
2017-12-01 13:54:05,074 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(ip1:port1):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1032] - Opening socket connection to server ip1:port1. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2017-12-01 13:54:06,974 [myid:] - WARN  [main-SendThread(ip1:port1):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1162] - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

I've done some search in add/remove zookeeper but didn't find a document for it. My zookeeper version (3.4.7) is not supported for dynamic reconfiguration (which is in zookeeper 3.5).
Is there a way I can manually remove/add zookeeper server from ensemble?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I've found the problem. There's a process within solr-webapp that use another config file that still point to old zookeeper host. It's not zookeeper's problem